# Expandable ListView GetChild returns null pointer-JAVA

Tags: java, android, adapter, expandablelistview

I have an expandable `ListView`.

`getChild()` method is working and returns perfectly on Toast,
but when I use it as

```
String s=getChild(Group,Child)
```

It returns nullpointer exception.

Here is my code.

in adapter class

```
  @Override
    public String getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return mListDataChild.get(mListDataGroup.get(groupPosition)).get(childPosition).toString();
    }
```

And I used it in adapterclass as;

```
childViewHolder.mCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

        if (isChecked) {


           switch (mGroupPosition) {
               case 0:
               case 1:
     String s=getChild(mGroupPosition,mChildPosition);
                   Toast.makeText(mContext,getChild(mGroupPosition,mChildPosition),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


      break;
```

In the code above, `getChild()` method works on Toast but returns null pointer on `s=getchild();`

Please help, Thank you!

Comment: What is the variable Toast?

Comment: @blahfunk Toast is just a class that allows you to show 'popups'. http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html

Comment: @Shree Krishna I can't understand what you say because if s=getChild(...) raises a NullPointerException, how can you know that the same getChild method works fine in the Toast message?? Anyway, this line: return mListDataChild.get(mListDataGroup.get(groupPosition)).get(childPosition).toString(); can cause 4 different NullPointerExceptions, so I suggest to refactor that line...

Comment: @Jorge It's not me who asked the question. I just edited it.

Comment: I know because i tried it by removinf s=getchild() line.
How can refactor it, do you have any idea?

Comment: Include some Null comparations like 'if (mListDataGroup.get(groupPosition) != null)' and so on, so you can make sure that you're recovering correct elements. If there's any null, it's easier to find it this way